# Probability of getting to all ones before back to all zeros

Tags: probability

In this problem we start with a vector of $n$ zeros. At each step we chose an index uniformly and independently at random  and flip the value at that index. Flipping a value means switching a $0$ to a $1$ or a $1$ to a $0$ depending on what is there. I am interested in the probability of getting to all $1$s before we get back to $0$s.

If $n=1$ the probability is $1$. The first step takes us to all $1$s.

If $n=2$ the probability is $1/2$.  After the first step there is a fifty percent probability of going to all $1$s and a  fifty percent probability of going back to all $0$s.

How can you would out the solution for $n>2$?

Comment: I tried to look into the case $n=3$, and broke the state space up into four groups: Those positions with exactly $k$ non-zero bits, where $k=0,\ldots,3$. The state transitions can be represented in a matrix

$$M = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \tfrac13 & 0 & \tfrac{2}{3} & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{2}{3} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0}$$

from which I calculate $p = \frac23 \frac13 \left( 1 + \left(\frac23\right)^2 + \ldots\right) = \frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: All ones first. Each summand in the calculation can be interpreted as "reaching 111 after first setting 2 bits without hitting 000, then alternating between the middle two states $n$ times before hitting 111".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw a state diagram like this (taking $n=3$ for example), with the main row showing the number of ones and the arrows showing the probability of transitioning backward or forward.

```
   1/3     2/3
  <----   <----   
0       1       2       3
          ---->   ---->
           2/3     1/3
```

Let $W_i$ be the probability of winning given $i$ ones. Then we have a system of equations
$$W_1 = \frac23 W_2\\
W_2 = \frac23 W_1 + \frac13$$
Having solved that, the value of $W_1$ is what you're looking for (given that you're effectively starting with one switch turned on).

Comment: Thank you. This is very clear.

Comment: In the $n=3$ case this gives you $2/5$.

Comment: @donald Yes, that's correct.

Comment: FWIW, these are the results for $n=3,\dots,20$: $\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{13},\frac{60}{151},\frac{105}{256},\frac{35}{83},\frac{63}{146},\frac{630}{1433},\frac{1155}{2588},\frac{6930}{15341},\frac{12870}{28211},\frac{24024}{52235},\frac{9009}{19456},\frac{9009}{19345},\frac{17017}{36362},\frac{306306}{651745},\frac{2909907}{6168632}$

Comment: @hgmath how did you compute those?

Comment: @donald by computer :) using a CAS

Comment: @hgmath very nice. Can I ask which CAS?

Comment: Interesting; these turn out to be the reciprocals of sums of reciprocals of binomial coefficients, e.g., $\frac1{\frac11+\frac14+\frac16+\frac14+\frac11}=\frac38$. See https://oeis.org/A046826. There is surely a nice combinatorial interpretation of the problem.

Comment: @Théophile That would be very interesting!

Comment: @donald I used Mathematica but I'm sure any CAS will do :)

Comment: The problem is really a random walk on a hypercube, with $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ being the "far corner". It makes sense that binomial coefficients would be involved.